# installing 32-bit version of Skype on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: skype

I'm having trouble installing Skype. I have Canonical Partners enabled in Synaptic Package Manager, but skype is not showing in the search. If I try to install via:

```
sudo apt install skype
```

I get:

```
E: Unable to locate package skype
```

I went to the Skype web site and it offered a .deb file only in 64 bit.

Comment: skypeforlinux is now 64-bit only. the old 32-bit skype is no longer supported nor does it work.

Comment: I edited and added "32-bit version" to the title as I suspect that's what you're trying to do (from "*I went to the Skype web site and it offered a .deb file only in 64 bit.*"). If it's not the case please revert this edit.

Answer (score 3):

It seems Skype's providing only 64-bit packages now.

As a workaround you may try [Rambox](http://rambox.pro/), an Electron based

> Free, Open Source and Cross Platform messaging and emailing app that combines common web applications into one.

*Skype* is among the [available services](https://github.com/saenzramiro/rambox#services-available---95) along with WhatsApp, Messenger, Viber, Telegram, Google Hangouts, Gmail, Twitter etc. There is also an option to add services manually.

To install Rambox, first download the [32-bit deb package](https://github.com/saenzramiro/rambox/releases/download/0.5.13/Rambox_0.5.13-ia32.deb) of the latest release (v0.5.13) from their [official GitHub page](https://github.com/saenzramiro/rambox/releases). Then run the following command in Terminal

```
sudo dpkg -i /path/to/the/package/package-name.deb
```

For example if you have downloaded the 32-bit package linked above to your Downloads folder then run

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/Rambox_0.5.13-ia32.deb
```

---

There's a similar application called [Franz](https://meetfranz.com/), but it seems it's recent release(s) offers only 64-bit packages. There is a [legacy version](https://github.com/meetfranz/franz-app-legacy/releases/tag/4.0.4) of the application with 32-bit packages.

Comment: No go. All 4 dependencies are installed on my system:

dpkg: error processing package rambox:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160824-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rambox:i386

Comment: After doing apt-get clean, autoclean, and autoremove,  I've successfully installed Rambox. But after clicking in Dash, it started and then crashed, just like Skype. Just one of those days...

Comment: Thank you @pomsky.  I'm going to stick to traditional phone line for my infrequent work calls for the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 2):

it's very very very simple. I use Skype for Web, just go here and login (http://web.skype.com). It will allow you to use any OS with any browsers without installing anything at all. No add ons, no downloads, nothing. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Skye provides a skype for web add on for chrome. This allows you to login without downloading skype. please look into this.